# Python Error: object.__new__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, api

I get the error:

```
object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

When I run the following program:

```
import urllib as net
class weather:
    api = "http://www.google/ig/api?weather="
    wData = None
    def _init_(self,location):
        self.api = self.api + location
        self.wData = net.urlopen(self.api).read()
    def showXML(self):
        return self.wData


w = weather("11570")
w.showXML()
```

Comment: What is the full traceback (including the line of code)?

Comment: Pity it's not going to work anyway: http://thenextweb.com/google/2012/08/28/did-google-just-quietly-kill-private-weather-api/

Comment: Two side notes. [`urllib.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) is deprecated, as the docs clearly say. And defining a classic class is always a bad idea; inherit from `object`. (And before anyone says "maybe it's 3.x", 3.x doesn't have a `urllib.urlopen`; `urllib` is a package, and the `urlopen` method is in the `url lib.request` library.)

Comment: Also, renaming something during import, except for specific idiomatic cases (like importing either `BeautifulSoup` or `bs4` as `bs`, importing `cPickle` as `pickle`, etc.) is almost always a bad idea. It makes your code confusing and harder to read for experienced Python devs.

Comment: as mentioned below, it's definitely 3; the `urlopen` line never actually runs.  it could just as well be `net.whatamidoingwithmylife` and he'd get the same error.  late binding, woo  :)

Comment: OK, in that case, the use of `urllib.urlopen` is even more of a problem, because that function isn't just deprecated, it's completely removed. But, more importantly, do not try to use 2.x sample code in 3.x without understanding the differences, or at least knowing how to look them up in the docs.

Answer (score 4):

You have:

```
def _init_(self,location):
```

Did you mean this?

```
def __init__(self, location):
```

Special method names always begin and end with two underscores.

Also it would've been nice to include a traceback, and mention the version of Python you're using—I assume 3, or your class wouldn't inherit from `object` by default.

Comment: It can't be 3, because there is no such thing as `urllib.urlopen` in 3.

Comment: it has to be 3; old-style classes would say "this constructor takes no arguments".  note that the program doesn't get far enough to notice that `urlopen` is gone...

Comment: I believe (although I don't have a copy to test with) that in 2.2-2.4, old-style classes got the same `TypeError` as new-style classes in this case. You're right, the OP _could_ be trying to evaluate 2.x code with a 3.x interpreter and he wouldn't have discovered his error yet, but I think using pre-2.5 is more likely.

Comment: On second thought… it still wouldn't say `object` in the message… So you're right, the OP _is_ trying to use a 2.x (and already deprecated in 2.x) API in 3.x…

Answer (score 1):

If you pasted your code verbatim, then there is an error in your `__init__` definition (notice, 2 `_` on each side)